# To restart the app from the home screen and not from the screen we left at

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

When we play our app on the device(ios 4.0 and above) and leave mid workflow, and return later, we return mid workflow.  I want that it should not replay from the same left point rather the main screen should load(i.e, the same thing that happens on calling viewDidLoad of our rootViewController).

Please give suggestions if it is possible and if not then please post the reason behind that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach, disable background mode and restart your app every time it enters the foreground: add **UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend** key to your app's info.plist and set its value to YES.

> UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend
>
> UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend (Boolean -
>   iOS) specifies that the application
>   should be terminated rather than moved
>   to the background when it is quit.
>   Applications linked against iOS SDK
>   4.0 or later can include this key and set its value to YES to prevent being
>   automatically opted-in to background
>   execution and application suspension.
>   When the value of this key is YES, the
>   application is terminated and purged
>   from memory instead of moved to the
>   background. If this key is not
>   present, or is set to NO, the
>   application moves to the background as
>   usual.
>
> This key is supported in iOS 4.0 and
>   later.

Comment: For Xcode 5+ it is now called "Application does not run in background" and you can set it to YES

Answer (score 1):

So actually you want to quit the app on Home button press and restart?i.e turn multitasking off?
Search for info on UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend

Answer (score 0):

Yes you call your rootviewcontroller from [applicationDidUnhide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008592-CH1-SW3) to do so. You'll have to twist your logic a  little (have to reset your variables on this method call).

Edit: You should instead use [applicationDidBecomeActive](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008592-CH1-SW3). Reference is on same link.