# How to reset iPhone App state every time it is started?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I've got an iPhone application, and I'd like it to reset its state every time the user leaves it, i.e. the home button is pressed. By "reset its state" I mean that the application should start as if it was started for the first time, and not resume from where the user left it. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may check this post, [To restart the app from the home screen and not from the screen we left at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790481/to-restart-the-app-from-the-home-screen-and-not-from-the-screen-we-left-at/)

Answer (score 0):

As you said, you *theoretically* could set that Boolean value in the info.plist file. However, you lose a lot of information like this. I recommend storing initial values in your app and load them every time te app starts. Tie your UI to those values.

Comment: i m doing this for lose my all info. i have that kind of application in that i want to reset all info. so i m doing this....

Comment: Yes, but what about when there's a phone call while someone is using your app?